# as little as VS. at least

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjunctions

What does "in **as little as** 4 days" mean? Does it mean within 4 days or **at least** 4 days?

Would anyone please show me if the following are interchangeable, if yes, when? when not? Meanwhile, would you show me a source to teach me such a subtle? I am really confused.

at least

as  little as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not mean the same.

The phrase *as little as* here means *just*, *only* and stresses the fact that it is 'not many, a small amount of' days.
For example:

> It took us **as little as** 4 days to finish the project.

means the same as

> It took us **only** 4 days to finish the project.
>
> It took us **only** four days to finish the project.

To which a possible response could be:

> Wow, only 4 days? That's quick!

*At least* is definitely different and expresses a minimum amount. It does not stress the small or large amount of *days*. It simply means *4 days **or more***. Since this is a very different meaning, you cannot use that and *as little as* interchangeably.