# Can "at least " be used in a positive sentence?

Tags: phrases

I found the sentence below on one of my dictionaries.

> The repairs will cost at least $100.

It seems to me that this is used when the repair cost is expensive to the speaker.

Can "at least " be used when the repair cost is not expensive to the speaker?

Comment: I don't really understand how you would use it that way.  "At least X" literally means "the minimum is X".  Can you provide an example of how you might use in a "positive" sense?

Comment: After another search, I found my answer may be this. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59300/as-little-as-vs-at-least

Comment: The burglar took the TV, but at least he didn't murder Grandma.

Comment: "At least" can be used to indicate a minimum. My mother's punishment for drunkenness will be at least a fine of £100, which we can pay, but, as she assaulted a police officer, she could go to prison, which would be inconvenient for the family.

Comment: The garage says that my car repair will cost **at least** £100, which I can afford, and **at most** £500, which I cannot.

Comment: You mean **a declarative sentence**.

Comment: "at least" means "a minimum of". By itself, it's neither positive or negative.  It's the context of the sentence which would determine if it was positive or negative . "I won at least £300 on a horse today!" compared to  "I was mugged last night and lost at least £300"

Answer (score 1):

I would use a sentence like this to inform you of the likely cost.

If I say “The repair will cost at least $100” and nothing else then I except that the cost is not significantly more, maybe $150 to $170, but not $200.

As part of a sentence I could say “The repair will cost at least $100, but I don’t know yet if X is damaged, which could cost thousands to fix.

Either way, there is nothing positive or negative about it. I just give you some information. If $100 is a lot of money for you or not I’d not my concern. It also gives you information about whether to do the repair: “There is a tiny scratch, hardly visible. The repair will cost you at least $100” - I give you the choice of living with the scratch or paying at least $100 to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A: ''The repairs will cost at least a hundred dollars.''

B: ''That's perfect, I can take this money from my mom and spend it at the party !''

A:''Exactly!''

Well, of course it's not good for the mom in our story...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the speaker has an insurance policy with no coverage for repairs less than $100 but only a $50 copay for larger jobs.
So the speaker would be happy to hear "at least $100".

(That unlikely policy would encourage collusion between the speaker and the repair shop.)

Answer (score 0):

If repairs are "at least" $100, then they could be much more. Even if someone finds $100 to not be a significant amount of money, that doesn't mean they wouldn't find more money to be significant. There's really no way that "at least" can indicate an insignificant amount.

Answer (score 0):

I think your intuition is correct: "at least" is typically used when the amount is more than some other relevant threshold.

Whether it's "positive" or "negative" depends on context:

- I'm inheriting at least $10,000 (positive)
- It will take us at least 3 hours to get there (negative)

But you don't use it when the amount is smaller than what would be valuable/desirable/useful:

- I'm inheriting at least $10,000 but I need a million dollars to buy this house. (confusing)
- I'm only inheriting $10,000 but I need a million dollars to buy this house. (good)
- I'm inheriting at least $10,000 so I should be able to come on the trip. (good)

Or:

- It will take us at least 3 hours to get there so we don't need to leave yet.  (confusing)
- It will only take us 3 hours to get there, so we don't need to leave yet. (good)
- It will take us at least 3 hours to get there so we should leave now. (good)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could say something like, *At least the repairs were under $500.*

There are at least two definitions for *at least*.  My usage above means *all things considered*, definition 2 in most cases.

You cannot, however, mix the two meanings. Either you mean *at the minimum* or you mean *all things considered*.